# Reopen this question

Tags: support

[I installed kali linux with the dual boot on ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042007/i-installed-kali-linux-with-the-dual-boot-on-ubuntu-16-04)

It is not a question about Kail linux, it is a question about recovering Ubuntu

I agree we do not support Kali

I agree the op should have made backup

We do, however, support Ubuntu data recovery after I stalling other os windows specifically

[Recover Windows 7 boot after installing Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524511/recover-windows-7-boot-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04)

[recovering lost data after installing ubuntu on windows 10 using testdisk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/827414/recovering-lost-data-after-installing-ubuntu-on-windows-10-using-testdisk)

[How to recover GRUB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991420/how-to-recover-grub)

So I believe we should help in this case as well

Comment: Just a thought: if we reopen it, it's likely to be closed as a duplicate of one of those other posts.  Thus, it is ultimately going to end up as closed either way.

Comment: I think close g as a duplicate is preferable and some of the comments might appear snarky. How would you feel if you made a mistake and were asking for help and got similar comments ?

Comment: The question has been reopened. You're right, that wasn't the correct close reason.

Answer (score 3):

Agreed. If the question is on topic, it should not be closed as off topic.

I have now reopened it although, as Thomas pointed out, it will likely be closed as a dupe. At least it will be closed for the right reason if so.

Comment: Thank you for your time and consideration

Comment: @Panther you're welcome. But since you did mention snark, please don't leave comments like "Google data recovery". That isn't helpful and is unpleasant.

Comment: I  know there  a long standing dislike of RTFM and google here, but I am afraid we will  have to agree to disagree on this point . google is a useful tool and the "teach a man to fish", IMHO,  applies. Sometimes , it is best to guide people how to RTFM, man pages, ubuntu documentation, duplicate questions here, and yes sometimes even google. Teaching people how to self help / self learn is very helpful . In this case, I left a comment on a closed question, best I could do at the time. Now that the question is re-opened, I have given additional advice and asked for additional information.

Comment: @Panther great, thanks for that! But if you feel that the best thing to do is "google foo" then it's usually better to walk away. That really isn't helpful if the OP is already asking about foo. It is a good indication that you might want to downvote, but telling people to google something isn't teaching them to fish, it's telling them that fishing exists. I think it's safe to assume they already knew that, but chose not to do it.